# How to access element value in my %hash from an another package perl

Tags: perl, hash, hashtable

I have a hash inside a package name:
**./lib.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

package lib;

#my %hash = (
our %hash = (
    Addr =>
    {
        'aa' => 0x11223344,
        'bb' => 0x55667788,
        'cc' => 0xaabbccdd,
    },
);
```

And i tried to access all of their elements from another package with some ways as below:
**./check.pm**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;
unshift( @INC, $dir );
require lib;

print "========================\n";
print "1: $lib::hash{Addr}{'aa'}\n";
print "2: $lib::hash{Addr}{'bb'}\n";
print "3: $lib::hash{Addr}{'cc'}\n";

print "========================\n";
printf (sprintf("%8X\n", $lib::hash{Addr}{aa}));
printf (sprintf("%8X\n", $lib::hash{Addr}{bb}));
printf (sprintf("%8X\n", $lib::hash{Addr}{cc}));

print "========================\n";
my ($Address_a, $Address_b, $Address_c);
my (@Address_a, @Address_b, @Address_c, @names);
$Address_a = sprintf("%8X", $lib::hash{Addr}{'aa'});
$Address_b = sprintf("%8X", $lib::hash{Addr}{'bb'});
$Address_c = sprintf("%8X", $lib::hash{Addr}{'cc'});
@Address_a = ( $Address_a =~ m/../g );
@Address_b = ( $Address_b =~ m/../g );
@Address_c = unpack("(A2)*", $Address_c);

printf "========================\n";
printf ("@Address_a \t\n");
printf ("@Address_b \t\n");
printf ("@Address_c \t\n");

printf "========================\n";
printf ("$Address_a[0], $Address_a[1], $Address_a[2], $Address_a[3]\n");
printf ("$Address_b[0], $Address_b[1], $Address_b[2], $Address_b[3]\n");
printf ("$Address_c[0], $Address_c[1], $Address_c[2], $Address_c[3]\n");
```

And i got result normally:

```
========================
1: 287454020
2: 1432778632
3: 2864434397
========================
11223344
55667788
AABBCCDD
========================
========================
11 22 33 44
55 66 77 88
AA BB CC DD
========================
11, 22, 33, 44
55, 66, 77, 88
AA, BB, CC, DD
```

But when i change the way of hash declaration from "*our %hash*" to "*my %hash*", the result is gone:

```
========================
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./check.pm line 10.
1:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./check.pm line 11.
2:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./check.pm line 12.
3:
========================
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 14.
       0
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 15.
       0
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 16.
       0
========================
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 20.
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 21.
Use of uninitialized value in sprintf at ./check.pm line 22.
========================
          0
          0
    0
========================
  ,   ,   ,  0
  ,   ,   ,  0
, , ,  0
```

Is there any change i need when getting data from "my %hash"?

Comment: `lib` is the name of a [pretty important and ubiquitous Perl pragma](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib); it's not a great name for one of your own packages.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I just make it as an example. I will never use it in real task.

Comment: You must *understand* the code you are writing and *choose* what to write on that basis. It is ***never*** correct to write stuff "because it worked before" or "because I've seen it done". Please justify `#!/usr/bin/perl -w` beyond *"It's what I write at the top of every Perl program"*

Comment: Yes, sure. I'm on this way with some trial code to undersand how hash working in perl :)

Comment: For the -w option, is it use for giving message/warning in detail when exist some problem inside code?

Comment: @HungNguyen: That's my point: if you don't know what it does then you shouldn't write it. It's easy enough to google. How do you think it's different from `use strict` and `use warnings`? You also need to be clear what the *shebang* `#!` line does and what it's for: you don't always need it. If you *learn the language* properly then you wouldn't have so much need to constantly ask the rest of the world for help on, say, *Stack Overflow*.

Answer (score 4):

[my](http://p3rl.org/my) declares a lexical variable, and you can't extend the scope of a lexical variable, i.e. share it outside the package.

Why can't you use an [our](http://p3rl.org/our) variable?

You can't share the lexical variable, but you can share its value. For example, you can provide a closure in the package that exposes the value:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

{   package MyLib;

    my %hash = (
        Addr => {
            aa => 0x11223344,
            bb => 0x55667788,
            cc => 0xaabbccdd,
        },
    );
    sub get_hash { %hash }

}


my %hash = MyLib::get_hash();
print "========================\n";
print "1: $hash{Addr}{'aa'}\n";
print "2: $hash{Addr}{'bb'}\n";
print "3: $hash{Addr}{'cc'}\n";
```